# flyway gradle plugin with groovy environments

Tags: gradle, flyway, gradle-plugin

I am trying to customize gradle to build to get flyway properties from groovy file

my environment.groovy file

```
environments {
    dev {
        flywayProperties {
            driver="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
            url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/XE"
            user="test"
            password="test"
            locations= "classpath:db/migration,db/insert"   
        }
    }

    qa {
        flywayProperties {
            driver = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
            url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/XE"
            user = "test"
            password = "test"
            locations = "classpath:db/migration"
        }
    }
}
```

and my build.gradle

```
loadConfiguration()

task printProps << {
    println "Driver:  $config.flywayProperties.driver"
    println "URL:  $config.flywayProperties.url"
    println "User:  $config.flywayProperties.user"
    println "Password:  $config.flywayProperties.password"
    println "Locations:  $config.flywayProperties.locations"
}

def loadConfiguration() {
    def environment = hasProperty('env') ? env : 'dev'
    project.ext.envrionment = environment
    println "Environment is set to $environment"

    def configFile = file('environment.groovy')
    println configFile.toURL()

    def config = new ConfigSlurper("$environment").parse(configFile.toURL())
    project.ext.config = config
}

flyway {
    driver = "$config.flywayProperties.driver"
    url = "${config.flywayProperties.url}"
    user = "${config.flywayProperties.user}"
    password = "${config.flywayProperties.password}"
    //locations = ['classpath:db/migration' , 'db/insert']   -- Works fine
    locations = "${config.flywayProperties.locations}" -- Throws below error
}
```

I get below error when I try to execute 'gradle flywayInfo'

> **FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>   * What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':flywayInfo'.
>
> > Error occurred while executing flywayInfo Unknown prefix for location (should be either filesystem: or classpath:): :**

Can someone help me how to provide locations. As i need to provide multiple locations based on the environments

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try just:

```
 locations = config.flywayProperties.locations
```

?

Answer (score 0):

I met the same issue caused by the wrong type. given the `String` but `String[]` expected.

Please modify like this

```
locations = "${config.flywayProperties.locations}".split(',')
```

The next question is why the exception happened as you paste?

Because the coercion from `String` to `String[]` will result in a wired issue. For example,

```
(String[])"filesystem:xxx"
=> [f, i, l, e, s, y, s, t, e, m, :, x, x, x]
```

hmm, really wired. so all will be clear when we review the flyway Location code [here](https://github.com/flyway/flyway/blob/75b1913311f50e91efbe591c322d8ba7366e52c1/flyway-core/src/main/java/org/flywaydb/core/api/Location.java#L95).

all single-word `String` will be skipped except `:` in [f, i, l, e, s, y, s, t, e, m, :, x, x, x]

the `normalizedDescriptor` is the `:` that will throw as a signal that is not matching `filesystem` or `classpath`.